# Execute a function with respect to the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to execute a function with respect to the clicked element (here div with `.redactor` class).

If clicked the specified element (`.redactor`), then execute this function:

```
$('.redactor').on("click", function() {
    $(".redactor").each(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass("selected"))
        {
             destroy_redactor(current_edit);
             $(this).removeClass("selected");
        }
    });

    $(this).addClass("selected");
    current_edit = $(this);
    initialize_redactor(current_edit);
});
```

Or if clicked other than the specified element, execute this function if there is already an initialized redactor or else do nothing:

```
destroy_redactor(current_edit);
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it#answer-7385673) as a reference. But it is not helping. It just removes all the divs.

I can't figure out how to execute the `destroy_redactor(current_edit)` function when clicked outside the `.redactor` div while there is already an initialized redactor for the `current_edit`.

Sample in [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Kakar/pen/bVNEOy)

Answer (score 0):

how about adding the click listener on the document...

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
  var target = $(event.target);

  if (target.attr('class') == 'redactor') {
     //do something with it
  }
  else{
     // clicked on none of the redactor elements 
  }
});
```

if you need to find if there is a redactor active you can do something like this

```
$(".redactor.active") //will get you a div with both redactor and active class
```

Comment: When clicked inside the `.redactor` div, its just taking the target as the child elements and not the `.redactor` div itself. How to correct this? Please could you check it with this [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Kakar/pen/bVNEOy)

Comment: if it returns a children of it (if you will click in the h1 it will return the h1 as target) you can check if the element is children of a redactor div like this
if(target.parents(".redactor").length!=0) 
   // ok i'm a redactor child
else
   // i'm not a redactor child

Comment: anyway if you try as i said you need to remove your $('.redactor').on('click') otherwise this will conflict with the $(document).click

Comment: Yes now its differentiating between inside and outside nicely. But after removing the `$('.redactor').on("click")` , I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null`.

Comment: when are you getting this error? when you click something, when you load the page, or when?
in the codepen.io i do not get that error